# nvd3.js: pie chart tooltips blinking in IE 10

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, pie-chart, nvd3.js

Tooltips are blinking on hover.

It can be reproduced in pie chart in IE 10.

Example: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8xX4dgtJhD4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found a very easy fix that may or may not be satisfactory for you, but I added a `top:50px` to the `.nvtooltip` css class. That fixed the height of the tooltip and avoided the cursor from moving over it. Not an ideal solution but extremely easy to implement. Hope this helps.